# What does AA mean?

Tags: terminology, smite

> Land her 3, then trap with ult and cast 2 for body blocking and spam the aoe of your 3 on AA and watch them die
>   - [Reddit's MANJAROWOLF](http://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/1xg4ym/your_opinion_on_the_top_3_hardest_mages_to/cfc1soi.)

I've seen this abbreviation quite a bit, but Google isn't helping. I keep thinking "anti-air", but that's not much of a thing in Smite. I suspect that this abbreviation also exists in other DotA-like (MOBA) communities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AA stands for auto-attack. Because you don't have to click once every time your character is ready to attack, it is so called auto-attack.

However, there is actually two type of AA, Active and Passive in MOBAs.

Active: You selected a target and your character attacks the target.

Passive: Character that is idle will look for the closest target within attack range, then reach and autoattack (note- there is no passive AA in Smite).

In other MOBAs, passive AA is on, but can be turn off in settings. Another fun fact is I found that more DotA 2 players prefer turning it off, while more LoL players prefer leaving it on.

Comment: Smite doesn't have Passive.

Comment: Yes. But I am explaining both anyway. While this question is tagged with Smite, I think this is a general gaming knowledge. I will now add note to the passive

Answer (score 0):

AA stands for auto-attack, also called standard, normal, or basic attack.

Comment: Googling "League of Legends AA meaning" helped.